# Continuous function that preserves relations induces continuous function.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

[My question arises from Exercise 1.11. in $\mbox{"An Introduction to Algebraic Topology"}$ by J. Rotman.]

Suppose that $X$,$Y$ are topological spaces with equivalence relations $\sim$ and $\sim'$, respectively, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map preserving the relations. I need to show that the induced map $\bar{f}: ({X/\sim})  \rightarrow ({Y/\sim'})$ is also continuous.

Let $U\subset Y/\sim'$, $\; \bar{f}^{-1}(U)\neq\varnothing$ and $\nu_{\sim},\nu_{\sim'}$ the natural maps.

I intuit that since $\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$ (quotient topology of $U/\sim'$) which gives that $f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim}^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X$ ($f$ is continuous) which, consequently, gives that $\nu_{\sim}(f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim}^{-1}(U)))$ is open ($\nu_{\sim}$ is open map), $\bar{f}$ must be continuous.

Does $\bar{f}^{-1}(U)\;$ equals to $\;\nu_{\sim}(f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U)))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and this is just a matter of chasing the definitions.  Suppose that $a\in \bar{f}^{-1}(U)$.  Then $a=\nu_{\sim}(b)$ for some $b\in X$, and $\nu_{\sim'}(f(b))=\bar{f}(a)\in U$.  Thus $b\in f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$ and so $a\in \nu_{\sim}(f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U)))$.

Conversely, suppose $a\in \nu_{\sim}(f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U)))$.  Then $a=\nu_{\sim}(b)$ for some $b\in f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$.  We then have $\bar{f}(a)=\nu_{\sim'}(f(b))\in U$ and thus $a\in \bar{f}^{-1}(U)$.

---

Note though that this does *not* solve the problem you started from in the way you describe, since contrary to what you say, $\nu_{\sim}$ is *not* typically an open map.  To conclude that $\nu_{\sim}(f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U)))$ is open you need to show not just that $f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$ is open but also that it is saturated with respect to $\sim$ (i.e., if $x\in f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$ and $y\sim x$ then $y\in f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$).

Comment: Thank you Eric for the note! 
So, in order to show that $f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$ is saturated, that is it contains all the equivalents of its elements modulo $\sim$, let $x\in f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$ and $x\sim y$. The pre-image $\nu^{-1}(U)$ is the union of the equivalence classes modulo $\sim'$ (in form of sets), thus $z\in\nu^{-1}(U), w\sim' z \Rightarrow w\in\nu^{-1}(U)$. Since $f$ preserves relations, $f(x)\sim'f(y)$, we have $y\in f^{-1}(\nu_{\sim'}^{-1}(U))$.